# Create and communicate with a non-terminating shell via child_process in nodejs

Tags: node.js, powershell

Is there a way to spawn a single `child_process` in NodeJS and pass it various commands over time keeping the same process open as long as necessary? Sort of like a spawned terminal which accepts commands from Node.

Why? Performance.

I have a NodeJS/Electron application which should execute powershell commands and this is achieved using Node's `child_process` module. However the performance is not great: there appears to be a couple of seconds overhead each time I spawn a child process (which is to be expected I suppose).

This means that commands such as `Get-Date` take 600ms instead of a few (2) milliseconds. Other commands take 2+ seconds instead of say 800ms.

Desired workflow:

1. Start a child powershell process (exec with shell = powershell)
2. Pass it a command
3. Get the results (stdout/stderr)
4. Wait seconds to minutes for the user...
5. Pass it a second command
6. Get the results (stdout/stderr)
7. etc...
8. Close child process

I have considered writing powershell commands from NodeJS to a file `commands.txt`. Next I would start a single powershell child_process which watches/tails a file for new commands and executes them, passing the output into another file which the parent (NodeJS) process watches. This seems a bit hacky however...

Comment: _Pass it a command_ is tantamount to _interprocess communication_.  So choose an IPC method and go with it.  Streaming via stdin stdout works as IPC.  So what's the problem?

Comment: Are you referring to `child_process.fork` with messaging? Otherwise, I don't get how my child process can stay "alive" waiting for commands so please explain...

Comment: I think I understand now.  Assuming the child process is powershell.exe then you'll have to use whatever existing IPC mechanisms it provides, and you're asking _what IPC mechanisms are available to control a single instance of powershell_, right?

Comment: I guess I am - when I, as a user start powershell I can enter commands ad infinitum and I imagine the same must be true of a "hidden" process somehow.

Comment: I don't like how the title and first part of your question sounded like you just want to know how to spawn a process and send it commands (as if you had written both parent and child applications).  But then suddenly by paragraph 3 of your question you reveal that it's actually powershell that you're trying to deal with.  I realize you have a powershell tag, but I feel like the title should be changed, because your intent is only to solve the problem for powershell.

Comment: OK, but it really doesn't matter to me which shell I am working with. If anyone offers a cool solution which works with bash or cmd.exe or python.exe I would accept it and use that paradigm. I'd really be keen to hear your IPC ideas since I have only come up with the stdio solution so far and it's kinda clunky.

Answer (score 1):

I have found one solution using `spawn` and periodically piping input to the process with `stdin.write`:

```
const { spawn } = require("child_process");

const ps1 = spawn("C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe", [], {});
console.log("PID", ps1.pid, "started");

ps1.stdout.on('data', (data)=>{
  console.log("STDOUT:"+data);
});

ps1.stderr.on('data', (data)=>{
  console.log("STDERR:"+data);
});

ps1.on('close', (code, signal) => {
  console.log(`child process terminated due to receipt of signal ${signal}`);
});

setInterval(()=>{
  ps1.stdin.write("Get-Date\n");
}, 1000);
```

**Results**:

```
PID 7688 started
STDOUT:Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


STDOUT:PS W:\powershell\powowshell\bak>
STDOUT:Get-Date

STDOUT:

STDOUT:Freitag, 17. Mai 2019 17:55:52

STDOUT:


STDOUT:PS W:\powershell\powowshell\bak>
STDOUT:Get-Date

STDOUT:

STDOUT:Freitag, 17. Mai 2019 17:55:53
```

So now it's "just" a case of stripping whitespace and other fuzz and getting the results.